# Custom Exception Class C++

Tags: c++

I would write a custom exception class but it's not possible because i have an error.

SSException.h :

```
#ifndef SSEXCEPTION_H
#define SSEXCEPTION_H

#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

class SSException: public std::exception {

public :
    virtual const char* what() const throw();

private:
    const char* errMessage_;

};

#endif
```

SSException.cpp :

```
using namespace std;

const char* SSException::what() const throw()
{
    return "UNKNOW";
}
```

I would have a custom method such as :
virtual const char* getMsg(int code);

But this solution, doesn't work. Can you help me ?
Implementation:

```
try {
   st.timeRef();
    }   catch(const SSException& ex)    {
        //cerr << "Solar System Exception: \n" << ex.what() << endl;
        cerr << "Solar System Exception: \n" << ex.getMsg(2) << endl;
    }
```

Error :

> SolarSystem.cpp:26:54: error: passing ‘const SSException’ as ‘this’
>   argument of ‘virtual const char* SSException::getMsg(int)’ discards
>   qualifiers [-fpermissive]    cerr << "Solar System Exception: \n" <<
>   ex.getMsg(2) << endl;

Thank you in advance

Comment: You need a const member function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would have a custom method such as : virtual const char* getMsg(int code);

It would need to be `virtual const char* getMsg(int code) const;`, because your code catches by constant reference.
In this case `const` just means that the function `getMsg` doesn't modify its object.

Comment: Very thanks you !
I understand. Than you for this explanation.

Comment: @AkrogAmes feel free to accept the answer if that's all you need.